# Conditions based on resources on yaml pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 2 Git repositories: one with the source code of the application, one for the DevOps pipelines.

For the second stage of the pipeline, I want to check if the branch that triggered the pipeline is master.
But the problem is the variable **Build.SourceBranchName** has the information of the DevOps repository, not the repository containing the source code (repository named *hidden*).

I don't see any variable that can be used for that purpose.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: 'hidden'
    type: git
    name: 'hidden/hidden'
    trigger:
    - master
    - develop

trigger: none

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  variables:
  - name: BuildConfiguration
    value: 'Release'
  - name: ApiSolution
    value: 'Company.WebApi.csproj'

  jobs:
  - job: BuildAPI
    displayName: 'Build API'

    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: hidden

    - script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'env | sort'
[...] 

- stage: DeployDev
  displayName: 'Deploy dev stage'

  dependsOn: Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'))

  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployServiceApp
    displayName: 'Deploy system to the dev environment job'

    workspace:
      clean: all
      
    environment: 
      name: 'xyz'
      resourceType: 'VirtualMachine'

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
[...]
```

Does someone has a solution for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try fetch detail via `$[ resources.repositories['other'].ref ]` as it shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-details)

I tested this today and now it works:

```yaml
name: ref-name

trigger: none
pr: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      type: github
      name: kmadof/devops-templates
      endpoint: kmadof
    - repository: azure
      type: git
      name: 'DevOps Manual/azure-functions'

variables:
  test: "true"
  azure.ref: $[ resources.repositories['azure'].ref ] 
  tools.ref: $[ resources.repositories['devops'].ref ] 
  isMain: $[eq(resources.repositories['devops'].ref, 'refs/heads/master')]

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: devops
- checkout: azure
- script: env | sort
  displayName: Print env variables
- bash: |
    echo "Tools version: $TOOLS_REF"
    echo "Tools version: $AZURE_REF"
    echo "Tools version: $ISMAIN"
```

Comment: It only works for "pipeline" resource, I'm trying to do it for "repository" resource.
I tried "resources.repository.hidden.sourceBranch" but it does not work

Comment: @Thibault Sorry, I was somehow blind adding my original reply. I edited it with sth what should help you.

Comment: Thanks !
Where can I find all the variables that I can use ? 'ref' is the only one working I found.

Comment: This all what I found too.

Comment: @Thibault Can you consider upvoting my answer if it was helpful for you?

Comment: The condition  `- ${{ if eq(variables['TOOLS_REF'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:`  always returns false. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Probably you can't use this in that way '${{` is compile expression and `$[` is runtime expression. So at compilation tools_ref is evaluates to empty/null value. Please try use `tools.ref` variable in condition (but not on expression).

Comment: Strange. I tested it and there is an issue with getting `ref`. I created a ticket on [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1252381/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje-62.html)

Comment: @Thibault if you still needs this please check it again. It looks that it works now :)

Comment: it works with the condition, indeed. Thanks for the follow-up.
I was hoping it will work with the compile if statement but this is not working. I will have to adapt. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

We could add task bash and add script `printenv` to print all env variable, then I found this variable `BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH`, it is the full trigger branch name, such as `refs/heads/master`

Result:

[image]

Also, If you can't find the variable you need in the environment variable, we could add power shell script and use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to check the trigger branch.

Comment: I may need the name of the source branch of ALL the resources. Not only the one that started the pipeline.